# Android - Preference screen not showing preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have a Preference Activity 
But, whenever I call it, the preferences are empty. No title or summaries are visible. You can click on the preference and it will highlight but there is no text. I have tried adding an EditTextPreference and in that case an edit text will pop up on click but there is no text.

Activity:

```
 public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:title="SomePref"
        android:summary="Somethingsomething"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm using the ActionBarSherlock library and I was extending the regular PreferencesActivity when it should have been **Sherlock***PreferencesActivity

Everything works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add this inside `PreferenceScreen` and see what happens:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Preference Category">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="True"
        android:key="checkbox_key"
        android:title="CheckBox Title"
        android:summaryOn="Checkbox is ticked"
        android:summaryOff="Checkbox is not ticked" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always, throughout the app save your preferces through getApplicationContext(), if you use this as context it will save with activity context and cannot retreived all the time